# Want to install yahoo Boomerang in GWT project

Tags: html, gwt, yahoo

I want to install yahoo Boomerang in my project ..

and also want to see the performance of my site using Boomerang ......

Please suggest me ...

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far, and what didn't work about it?

Comment: For the record, "Boomerang is a piece of JavaScript that you add to the bottom of your Web pages, where it measures page-load time, among other things, and beacons the results back to your server." See http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2010/06/performance_testing_with_boomerang.html and http://github.com/yahoo/boomerang for more info about Boomerang.

Comment: but where should I see the result?

Comment: Why not use SpeedTracer (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/) instead? It works great with GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on how to use boomerang is here: http://lognormal.github.io/boomerang/doc/howtos/index.html

If you want to see the results as charts and do statistical analysis, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Build your own backend to receive and process the data.
2. Send the data to something like piwik or google analytics that will let you see timeseries charts
3. Use a commercial service that already does this like SOASTA's mPulse [disclaimer, I wrote boomerang and I'm the Chief Architect behind mPulse]